# Simultaneously augmenting X,y in Keras

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, keras, deep-learning

I want to simultaneously augment `X` (500,28,28,1), `Y` (500,28,28,1) imageset in keras and store them in an array for visualizing results (before i can train a network). **The output y is not a label but an image.**

I copy `X_train` in `y_train` (Mnist dataset) and i want to apply same effects in both `x`, `y` for training a network. However, i am unable to do transofmration for both X and y. I am getting ZCA on X only.My code is :

'''

```
(X_train, y_train), (X_test, y_test) = mnist.load_data()
X_train = X_train.reshape((X_train.shape[0], 28, 28, 1))
X_train = X_train.astype('float32')
y_train=X_train

datagen = ImageDataGenerator(zca_whitening=True)

datagen.fit(X_train)
datagen.fit(y_train)

training_set=datagen.flow(X_train,y_train,batch_size=100):
temp=np.asarray(training_set[0])
```

'''

temp[0...] has ZCA applied whereas temp[1..] doesnt have any effect

Comment: X is an image and y is a label. Why would you apply same effects on two entities that serve entirely different purposes?

Comment: If you read the code above, i have declared the y_train=X_train

Answer (score 1):

You need to pass **pairs** of `X_train, y_train` and `X_test, y_test` as arguments to `datagen`'s `flow` method. Here's an example:

```
datagen = ImageDataGenerator(zca_whitening=True)

datagen.fit(X_train) # to compute quantities required for featurewise normalization

training_set = datagen.flow(X_train, y_train, batch_size=100)
test_set = datagen.flow(X_test, y_test, batch_size=100)

classifier.fit_generator(training_set, validation_data=test_set, epochs=100)
```

This allows for *simultaneous augmentation* of input `X` and corresponding ground-truth labels `Y` for training the neural network.

Hope this helps!

Here are a few references for the same: [1](https://medium.com/datadriveninvestor/image-processing-for-mnist-using-keras-f9a1021f6ef0), [2](https://yashk2810.github.io/Applying-Convolutional-Neural-Network-on-the-MNIST-dataset/) & [3](https://machinelearningmastery.com/image-augmentation-deep-learning-keras/)

Comment: Thanks @Balraj i am trying to store the data in an array and not pass it for training.
How can i retrieve the images from training_set ?

Comment: Since I cannot check this right away, I guess `training_set[0]` should give the augmented `X_train'` dataset.

Comment: Actually, in an edit, I added `dataset.fit(X_train)` line to the above code a while back which I'd missed earlier. That is necessary for the ZCA effect or any other normalization effect. Could you please run the augmentation part again and confirm you're not getting ZCA augmentation?

Comment: well, training_Set[0] is a tuple so i convert it to narray:
ary=np.asarray(training_Set)
which gives me (2,100,28,28,1) array...
Then i consider both ary[1..] and ary[0..] but both have same images, with ZCA effect only in ary[0...] images and not in ary[1...] images 
I am expecting both to have same effects or may be i am interpreting this wrong
Please help me when you get time Thanks

Comment: I tried to add dataset.fit(y_train)

But the training_set have no effect

Comment: My problem is that i have 5 images in X (array size (5,28,28,1)) and 5 images as y(array size (5,28,28,1)). I want to train a network and want to make a dataset before that using datagenerator. Can you please guide me